# Convert binary string representation of a byte to actual binary value in Python

Tags: python, binary

I have a binary string representation of a byte, such as

```
01010101
```

How can I convert it to a real binary value and write it to a binary file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [the `int` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) with a `base` of `2` to read a binary value as an integer.

```
n = int('01010101', 2)
```

Python 2 uses strings to handle binary data, so you would use [the `chr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) to convert the integer to a one-byte string.

```
data = chr(n)
```

Python 3 handles binary and text differently, so you need to use [the `bytes` type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) instead. This doesn't have a direct equivalent to the `chr()` function, but the `bytes` constructor can take a list of byte values. We put `n` in a one element array and convert that to a `bytes` object.

```
data = bytes([n])
```

Once you have your binary string, you can open a file in binary mode and write the data to it like this:

```
with open('out.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: For python 2.6+, you're probably best off using `bytearray([n])`. [See doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray).