# convert huffman code string to binary

Tags: python, binary, huffman-code

I am having problem with how to convert huffman encoding string to binary python.

This question involves nothing of the huffman algorithm.

It is like this:

I can get an encoded huffman string, say `01010101010`. **Note**, it is a string.

But now I want to save the string representation into real binary.

In the huffman encoded string, every 0 and 1 is a **byte**.

What I want is every 0 and 1 is a **bit**.

How can I do that in python?

**Edit 1:**

Please forgive I did not describe my problem clear enough.

Let me explain my current approach of writing to zeros and ones to binary.

Say, we can a code string s='010101010'.

1. I use `int` to convert it to integer
2. Then use `unichr` to convert it to string so that I can write it to file
3. write the string to file in binary mode

Also to be noted, I need to read the file in order to decode the huffman code.

So my approach is,

1. read the bytes from file
2. restore them to int
3. convert the int to their binary representation string.
4. decode the string

And at **step 2**, the problem happens and I became clueless.

As some huffman string can be short(like, `10`), while some can be long(`010101010101001`). This results in their different byte length in their int value(
some short string may take just **one** byte,while long ones can take **two** or even more
)

The following code illustrates my problem:

```
ss=['010101','10010101010'] 
# first one is short and takes only one byte in its int value
# second one is long and takes two bytes   

print 'write it to file'
with open('binary.bin','wb') as f:
    for s in ss:
        n=int(s,2)
        print n
        s=unichr(n)
        f.write(s)

print 'read it to file'
with open('binary.bin','rb') as f:
    for s in f.read(): 
        print ord(s)
```

I am reading one byte a time in the second *with* part, but this is actually not correct. Because string `10010101010` takes up two bytes.

So, when I read those bytes from the file, How many bytes should I read at once?

Comment: There is an early version of a Huffman coder I threw together at http://pastebin.com/QEK3WdbE which shows how I do it.

Comment: http://packages.python.org/bitstring/functions.html#bitstring.pack

Comment: What have you tried? This should be easy compared to the work you've already done... what isn't working?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [convert binary representation string to binary in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213996/convert-binary-representation-string-to-binary-in-python) which you posted yesterday, where you accepted an answer. Why would you post it again?

Comment: Please forgive, I did not articulate this one clearly. It is different from the previous post, actually. Please see the edited version of my question.@Karl Knechtel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach(using *bitstring* library) which makes some sense, but still contain incorrectness:

Use **bitstring** library(Thanks to *Mechanical snail* and  *Marc B* )

For writing to file.

Steps:

1. encode the plain text to binary representation string
2. concatenate all those strings to form one longer one
3. use *bitstring.BitArray* to convert to hex format
4. write the hex string to a file

For reading:

1. read the hex string from file
2. convert it back to bit string using *BitArray*
3. start decoding

Code:

```
ss=['01010100','10010101010','010101110101010101'] #encoded message


from bitstring import BitArray,BitStream
print 'write it to file'
with open('binary.bin','wb') as f:
    s=''.join(ss);
    b=BitArray(bin=s)                 
    f.write(b.tobytes())# thanks to Scott, tobytes() method is very useful

print 'read it to file'
b=BitArray(filename='binary.bin')
print b.bin
```

Comment: The problem you have here is that you are writing a hex *string* to your file, not binary data. That is you're writing the 12 byte string `0x0a92a95d55` to file instead of the 5 bytes `\n\x92\xa9]U`. You might as well just write `01010100...` to the file! I would advise using the `b.tobytes()` method to convert to bytes (which pads with zero bits up to the byte boundary). These extra bits at the end could presumably be ignored by the decoder as they won't decode to any symbol. It's also important to pad at the end rather than the beginning.

Comment: So to write just use `f.write(BitArray(bin=''.join(ss)).tobytes())` and to read back you can either use `BitArray(filename='binary.bin')` or construct it from a read-only file object `BitArray(f)`.

Comment: Excellent. Really thanks, @Scott Griffiths I think it solved my problem perfectly!

Comment: @Scott Griffiths, the appending zeros actually caused some problems. It can be decoded to some symbol. At least in my case, it is so.

Comment: 太感谢了，正在找这个。事实就是python没办法用内置的函数很好解决这个问题，居然有人觉得这问题很简单实在是无语

Comment: @ScottGriffiths I was having the same exact problem.  It looks like your comment and package is the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different "binary" representations in Python that you might want to use.

### Bignum

One is a "bignum" or arbitrary-precision integer. This type is called `long` in Python 2.x and `int` in Python 3.x. As the name suggests, this representation is semantically an integer of arbitrary length, so it's useful if you plan to do arithmetic on the resulting number. To parse a string of binary digits, use

```
# Python 2
long(digit_str, 2)
```

or

```
# Python 3
int(digit_str, 2)
```

### `bitstring` library

Alternatively, as Marc B suggested in the comments, use the [`bitstring` library](http://packages.python.org/bitstring/index.html). Specifically, for conversion, use the [`bitstring.pack` function](http://packages.python.org/bitstring/functions.html#bitstring.pack).

For Huffman coding, using `bitstring` is probably preferable to storing data in a `byte`-string, since Huffman codes are generally not multiples of 8 bits; `bitstring` lets you manipulate bit-strings of arbitrary lengths. Disadvantage: `bitstring` is not part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You have a string that you need to convert into a number. `int` takes an optional 'base' as an argument. So for the string in your example,

```
>>> int('01010101010', 2)
682
```

Once you have a number (not a string), it doesn't make sense to want "real" binary, since the number is the same, you can display it in any base.  That means the binary `100` is the same number as the decimal `4`, inside your program they're not different numbers. So, once you turn your string into a number you can fiddle with the bits in it.

Comment: `'01'` and `'1'` are different codes. You need to encode the number of bits as well as the bit value.

Comment: good point, I took "This question involves nothing of the huffman algorithm" at face value, also didn't notice the duplicate question from yesterday.